# Is y * (1 - x / y) better than y - x for computing the difference of two floating numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Subtracting two floating point numbers in C++ can lead to [catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Is there any advantage to writing `y * (1 - x / y)` instead of `y - x`, in terms of numerical stability?

Comment: What is "catastrophic cancellation. "?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the error you'd hope to be able to improve upon?  Generally, efforts to avoid catastrophic cancellation involve techniques to avoid needing to subtract two similar numbers in the first place.

Comment: @EdHeal [catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)

Comment: No, with only 2 numbers, `y-x` is the best way of computing `y-x`.

Comment: I assume you're already read [this little gem](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). But for the sake of everyone else reading, it makes for good additional reading

Comment: @kwierman Does it relate to the question other than by being about floating-point? At what page?

Comment: Is there any benefit for this issue by using Fixed Point?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: No - the problem occurred *before* the subtraction.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The section is "Cancellation". It goes into depth on different types of cancellation, and the definition of errors produced by this mechanism.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: While I dislike the frequency with which WECSSKAFPA is linked to, the "Cancellation" section of the document has a clear explanation of the difficulties, and is very much related to the question.

Comment: @MarkDickinson It should be systematic to refer to a specific section or page of any 100-page document linked to in a comment. However I readily admit that I only asked for this page/section as part of an ongoing social experiment.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Shrug.  I dislike the frequency with which it's linked by people who have obviously never read it.  (Not saying this is the case here, but it gets used so often on SO to back up people's tragic superstitions that I really wonder what good linking to it can do.)

Comment: @tmyklebu It would be better if the people linking to it had actually read it, but that's because it would be better if *everybody* had actually read it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Haha, no. Catastrophic cancellation occurs the moment you decide you want to find the difference between two numbers, if those two numbers are nearly equal and far from 0. It doesn't matter how wacky a formula you use to do it -- the information required for a precise difference calculation has already been discarded.

In order to avoid the situation, you need to calculate and store *different numbers*. That is, instead of calculating and storing `x` and `y`, say, you'd calculate `a=x` and `b=y-x`. Or `a=(x+y)/2` and `b=(x-y)/2`. You wouldn't calculate them *from* `x` and `y` -- that would have exactly the same problem -- rather, you'd calculate and store them as the actual numbers, and calculate `x` and `y` as needed. (Obviously this requires a choice of `a` and `b` which can actually be calculated, given your use case.)

Comment: Yes!  In fact, if catastrophic cancellation occurs, the subtraction itself is guaranteed to be *exact*; there’s nothing you can do to get a more accurate result from `x` and `y`.  The only option is to find an alternative means of computing their difference directly.

Comment: Can you better explain your terminology "different numbers" and "the actual numbers"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps a better description might be "treat a different set of quantities as canonical".

Answer (score 6):

What you call "catastrophic cancellation" I call Sterbenz's theorem:  If a/2 <= b <= 2a, then the difference `b-a` is exactly representable.

The term "catastrophic cancellation" is something of a misnomer.  The subtraction is totally innocent; the catastrophe had already occurred when you rounded away the part of the number you wanted.

Comment: But, Sterbenz's theorem isn't that pervasive.  It can't guarantee exact representation when a=12 and b=5.

Comment: @JamesCurran: Sure, but that's not the 'catastrophic cancellation" OP is worried about.

Answer (score 4):

I'd think the the multiplication & division would give you more trouble, but nevertheless, in the long version, you are STILL subtracting two floating point numbers.

Answer (score 3):

the error you get from x-y is y times the one you get from 1-(x/y), that you later multiply by y, having the same result.